# Border in error template not showing for entire control

Tags: c#, wpf, errortemplate

I have given an error template for a textbox. But the template is not rendering correctly. The width of the border is that of the textblock in the previous row. It renders as shown below

[image]

But when I scroll the mouse or maximize the window, the border shows up around the entire textbox

[image]

My Error Template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorStyle">
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This textbox is part of a grid in a list box item template. The list box is part of another grid on which has `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` set to true.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             Margin="10,100,22,100"
             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="sharedColumn"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontStyle="Italic" Text="Class" Margin="4 7 4 4"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Row1 }" Margin="4 7 4 4" />

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Row 2"   Margin="4 11 4 4"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
                                     Grid.Row="1" 
                                     Text="{Binding Quantity , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, FallbackValue='0'}" 
                                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorStyle}"
                                     Margin="4 11 4 4" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Update:

If I remove the SharedSizeGroup and fix the width of the column, it works correctly. But I cant fix the column width like that

Comment: Shouldn't the border be around `AdornedElementPlaceholder`? Consider to prepare [mcve], you may find answer yourself while doing so. Currently your code required severe amount of work to try it.

Comment: If you remove your line Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorStyle}" then does it work as expected? You seem to be trying to reproduce the default error template... except with one that doesn't work.

Comment: Running your example does not reproduce the error you described.